Convert double to std_msgs::Float64 for ROS topic
I have to publish a float64 value in a topic and I'm using C++.
The problem is that the original value is a double, so I'm not able to find any way to convert the double into a float64 and publish it.
I tried to do it in this way:
Double encoder_sx = 10.0;
std_msgs::Float64 enc_sx = encoder_sx;
enc_pub.publish(enc_sx);

But it gives me errors because the compiler says that I cannot assign a double to std_msgs::Float64.
How can I fix this problem?
Thank you

The problem is that you're assigning an object of type std_msgs::Float64 a value of type double. Rather, you want to set the value of the std_msgs::Float64 object, which is of type double, another value of type double. In short: the types have to match in order to assign values.
The structure of a std_msgs::Float64 object is that it contains a variable called data of type float64. See the documentation for std_msgs/Float64 here.
So, to accomplish your goal from your given code, it would instead be:
std_msgs::Float64 msg;
double encoder_sx = 10.0;
msg.data = encoder_sx;
enc_pub.publish(msg);


Thanks a lot!! It worked like a charm!
